# Classfying image with multi standard

Tags: tensorflow, keras, classification

I'm not sure if it is right to describe this as "multi standard" but my problem is this.

I'm classfying pictures of fashion products,
and I want it to be classified some how like:

```
id, brand, product_kind, sex
1, gucci, wallet, woman
2, H&M, backpack, unisex
3, zara, coat, man
```

after searching I think it is similar to multi label classfication, but as for my understanding, multi label is more like:

```
id, gucci, H&M, zara, wallet, backpack, coat, woman, unisex, man
1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0
2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0
3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1
```

My purpose is to predict one from brand, one from kind, one from sex.
Could anyone recommend me any article or tutorial for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is basically 3 different classifiers, so the "easiest" would be to train three independent ones.

You can also have 3 independent output layers (with perhaps additional hidden layers for each of them), each of them with the traditional softmax outputs, and your cost function is the sum of the loss for each of these 3 layers. This way, the three classifiers share feature extractions and part of the logic.

Something like:

```
Features
   |
Hidden layer 1
   |
Hidden layer 2
   |-----------------------|--------------------|
Hidden layer 3-1      Hidden layer 3-2      Hidden layer 3-3
   |                       |                    |
Hidden layer 4-1      Hidden layer 4-2      Hidden layer 4-3
   |                       |                    |
softmax 1              softmax 2              softmax 3
```